# What is the difference between become and be become?

Tags: verbs, differences

What is the difference between become and be become?

For example,

> I become deaf.
>   I am become deaf.

Comment: Technically this is not a duplicate, but nevertheless it is answered in the questions [*Is it acceptable to use “is become” instead of “has become”?*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3402/is-it-acceptable-to-use-is-become-instead-of-has-become) and [*Oppenhimer's quote*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/505071/oppenhimers-quote). The first one especially has a thorough discussion of where this construction really comes from.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it acceptable to use "is become" instead of "has become"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3402/is-it-acceptable-to-use-is-become-instead-of-has-become)

Comment: Handel is the other common source: "The kingdom of this world *is become* the kingdom of our Lord and of his Christ".

Answer (score 41, accepted):

"I become deaf" is the present tense.

"I am become deaf" is an archaic form of the present perfect tense. Today, we would say, "I have become deaf." This phrasing is only familiar in J. Robert Oppenheimer's quoting of the *Bhagavad-Gita* in reference to the creation of the atomic bomb: "I am become death, the destroyer of worlds".

Comment: I can't help but wonder if Plutonium's question came from mishearing that quote.

Comment: And the popular Christmas song "Joy to the world, the lord *is* come"

Comment: Not just archaic, but an attempt to translate a poem from a foreign language.

Comment: @jamesqf I suspect "am" was chosen deliberately for poetic reasons.

Comment: It might be more correct to say that the phrase has entered contemporary English primarily via the famous Oppenheimer quote. [Google results](https://www.google.com/search?q=i+am+become+-oppenheimer+-death) *I am become deaf* might even be an intentional pun on the Oppenheimer quote.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this question was inspired by the *Epic Rap Battle* between Thanos and Oppenheimer https://youtu.be/v1vXC-vKgKg?t=75, where Oppenheimer indeed raps 'I am become deaf' in a pun on the 'I am become death' quote mentioned in this answer.

Comment: It's far older than Oppenheimer's quote (which was not his translation in any case). Handel's Messiah oratorio (or rather Charles Jennens's lyrics for it) includes the line "the kingdom of this world / **is become** the kingdom of our Lord" as part of its famous "Hallelujah" chorus.  That's 1745 or so.